# How to increment var number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap time-picker, I want to use that for any number of text-field, from 1 to any number, as its depend on members. I am pasting my code below, currently i have added "1" so its working for just one text-field, but If Members needed more than one text-field to show time ..how i can do that ?

```
var counterAvailabilityN = 1;

$('#es_availability_time_from' + counterAvailabilityN).timepicker();
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#timeDisplay').text($('#es_availability_time_from' + counterAvailabilityN).val());
}, 100);

$('#es_availability_time_from' + counterAvailabilityN).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
  $('#timeDisplay').text(e.time.value);
});


$('#es_availability_time_untill' + counterAvailabilityN).timepicker();
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#timeDisplay').text($('#es_availability_time_untill' + counterAvailabilityN).val());
}, 100);

$('#es_availability_time_untill' + counterAvailabilityN).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
  $('#timeDisplay').text(e.time.value);
});
```

Basically I am retrieving data "from to until" from database, so its some times coming with 3 text-fields and some time its coming with 5 text-fields, so i am unsure how many text-field will come from which member, If it is 3, i need to add 3 times time-picker in each text-field, If it is 5, I want to add 5 times time-picker, and as you see, i fixed it for 1, I just want on page load, it should read how many there and based on that add time-picker in each text-field, each text-field has different ID's, from 1 to any number.

Comment: You might want to look into event delegation, ideally you need to be able to set some delegation criteria, eg. instead of using ID's, use a class on the inputs, you can then assign an event to all inputs of type class x.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using Event delegation, it's not obviously using boostrap timepicker, but it will work for that too.

The example is very basic to make easy to follow.  Whatever you type into the from INPUT just gets copied into the to INPUT.

I've used three classes, for targeting the correct elements.

I've also used jQuery clone method to make multiple copies of elements, rather than hand coding it all in HTML.

```js
$(function () {
  var clone = $('#clone'), body = $('body');
  for (var l = 1; l < 10; l ++) {
    var cloned = clone.clone();
    cloned.removeClass('hidden');
    cloned.appendTo(body);
  }
  
  body.on('input propertychange', '.from', function () {
    var copyTo = $(this).parents('.fromto').find('.to');
    copyTo.val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- create a clone, make it's easy to create multiple ones -->
<div id="clone" class="fromto hidden">
  from <input class="from" />
  to <input class="to" />
</div>
```